# Remove all array element in mongodb which has id match in array

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an array of the id which I get from post request in nodejs. I want to remove all the elements in the orders array which match receive id array.

eg remove_id = ['60f1ab20891ced4818b5ea88','60f1ab20891ced4818b5ea87']
so I want to remove all elements from orders array whoose id match match remove_id array.

```
orderdetail = {
  _id: 60f1ab20891ced4818b5ea86,
  totalPrice: 400,
  orders: [
    {
      _id: 60f1ab20891ced4818b5ea87,
      quantity: 1,
      price: 200,
      name: 'Caramel Latte',
      category: 'Steaming Cups'
    },
    {
      _id: 60f1ab20891ced4818b5ea88,
      quantity: 1,
      price: 200,
      name: 'Cinnamon Latte',
      category: 'Steaming Cups'
    },
    {
      _id: 60f1ab20891ced4818b5ea89,
      quantity: 1,
      price: 200,
      name: 'Cinnamon Latte',
      category: 'Steaming Cups'
    }
  ],
  timestamp: 1626450720332,
  name: 'xxx',
  email: 'xxx',
}
```

what I have tried but not working,

```
Orderdetail.updateOne( { _id: '60f1ab20891ced4818b5ea86' }, { 
        $pull: { order: { _id: { $in: remove_id  } } } } )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename object name `order` to `orders` !

Try this code !

```
let remove_id = ['60f1ab20891ced4818b5ea87','60f1ab20891ced4818b5ea88']
db.getCollection('Orderdetail').updateOne({ _id: '60f1ab20891ced4818b5ea86' }, {
  $pull: {
    orders: { // rename this to orders 
      _id: { $in: remove_id }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: sorry for such a smaller issue.